# Assembly - inline asm - copy from one array to another?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, att

#### Context :

Linux 64. AT&T.

GCC 4.8.2 (with -O3 -march=native)

The x86_64 abi under my left hand, opened at page 21.

#### The intended C code :

So that the intent is made clear, here is the idea :

```
int32_t res[] = {0,0,0,0};
int32_t primo[] = {5,8,50,150};

for (int32_t x = 0; x < 4; ++x) {

    res[x] = primo[x];
}

printf("%d %d %d %d\n", res[0], res[1], res[2], res[3]);
```

#### The faulty C code :

Error detected :

```
Error: `(%rsp,%esi,4)' is not a valid base/index expression
```

The code :

```
int32_t res[] = {0,0,0,0};
int32_t primo[] = {5,8,50,150};
int32_t counter = 0;

    __asm__ volatile(
        "start_loop:\n\t"
        "movl (%1,%2,4), (%0,%2,4)\n\t"
        "addl $1, %2\n\t"
        "cmp $4, %2\n\t"
        "jne start_loop"
        : "=&r"(res)
        : "r"(primo),"r"(counter)
        :"cc"
        );

printf("%d %d %d %d\n", res[0], res[1], res[2], res[3]);
```

#### The assembly code (lines underlying the problem):

```
...
start_loop:
movl (%rsp,%edx,4), (%si,%edx,4)
addl $1, %edx
cmp $4, %edx
jne start_loop
...
```

#### The question :

How can I express the right code ? Where did I got it wrong ?

Thanks

## Update:

when changing the assembly line to

`movl (%rsp,%rdx,4), (%rsi,%rdx,4)`

I get

`Error: too many memory references for 'mov'`

What ??

## Update 2

For the readers, it seems that my system is quite special in that it will not put the right instruction size.

I have to manually type my variables with `int64_t`  as an example to force the r*x thing to happen. If c11/c++11 use `uintptr_t` type.

Otherwise, gcc sticks with the 32 bits version which causes invalid base/index error.

It has bitten me multiple times. I hope it won't for you now.

Comment: `esi` is a 32bit register. `si`, I hope, is a typo. And there is no `mov rm, rm` of course.

Comment: @harold:the compiler did it that way I fear. Even replacing with r*x, the problem remains..

Comment: That doesn't even compile due to impossible constraints, `res` being an array you can't use it as output. Also given your types, the compiler is unlikely to substitute 16 bit registers. Are you sure you are showing the correct code?

Comment: @Jester: I updated it. I added a & in =&r. So I have to name every slot for res as outputs ? I thought using the index notation would work

Comment: Note that the memcpy library routine (or your host language's equivalent) is already pretty darned well optimized,  and the compiler may be able to through-optimize it with surrounding code. Don't assume assembler, especially when written by folks who don't understand the deep behavior of processor and caches, will be faster. And remember that perfect optimization of something that accounts for 1% of runtime buys you less that 3% improvement of something that accounts for 50%... and takes infinitely more effort. First step in optimizing should always be to check that you're optimizing the righ

Comment: @keshlam: You are right, and this assembly is not aimed at high performance. It makes me learn first. And then, when that step will be solidly ongoing, one can beat the optimizing compiler, just for the sake/pleasure of the exercise. But you are right. If I have a specialized purpose, i can do better. But not right now :) yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now close the ABI doc, and open the intel manual, basic architecture and the instruction set reference of course :->

First of all, `mov` does not accept two memory operands, you have to go through a register or use the specialized string move `movs`. Second, in the effective address you can not mix 16, 32 and 64 bit registers. Given the types in your code fragment, it is highly suspicious that the compiler substituted 16 bit registers for you. Also, it shouldn't even compile due to impossible constraints, `res` being an array you can't use it as output. Furthermore you are changing the `counter` variable, but you don't tell the compiler that.

gcc inline assembly is a very complicated thing. Better avoid it if possible, especially if you are a beginner or else you will be fighting the compiler instead of learning assembly.

A fixed version may look like:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int32_t res[] = {0,0,0,0};
    int32_t primo[] = {5,8,50,150};
    int32_t counter = 0;
    int32_t tmp;

    __asm__ volatile(
        "start_loop:\n\t"
        "movl (%3, %q1, 4), %0\n\t"
        "movl %0, (%2, %q1, 4)\n\t"
        "addl $1, %1\n\t"
        "cmp $4, %1\n\t"
        "jne start_loop"
        : "=&r" (tmp), "+r" (counter)
        : "r" (res), "r"(primo)
        : "cc", "memory"
        );

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", res[0], res[1], res[2], res[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) It works. I missed the register thing. I am currently reading the Intel book. I will try to bushwhack through the MOVS instruction too to see if it can help. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: I understood something as to why the operands were not adjusted. I update the question

Comment: Jester, how comes it that res is an input operand and not considered read only ? i tried to displace it as an output, as it should be, but no way.. asm is not that consistent, right ?